# AADB2C user approval permission. Not able to access member user email addresses using Microsoft graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am working on AADB2C user approval permission.
I have logged in as a member user of that AADB2C.
I am using Microsoft graph api to fetch users list from azure active directory and add user to particular group etc.
When I fetch list of users from AADB2C then I get email addresses for only guest users and not of member users. 
Could you please help me to sort out this problem?

Thank You

Comment: How do you request get users ? I test in my lab and get all users in the directory successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get all users including members in My B2C tenant with Microsoft Graph :

Login Microsoft Graph Explorer with a global admin account , here is my request and response:

[image]

However, I don't recommend you use Microsoft Graph API to manager users in Azure AD B2C .Because Microsoft Graph cannot manager users in B2C tenant for now. This feature is coming soon. See the comparision of  Azure AD Graph API and Microsoft Graph in [this blog](https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph).

Try to use [**Azure AD Graph API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart) instead Microsoft Graph.

Login Azure AD Graph Explorer with a member and globl admin account.Use this Request to Get users in B2C tenant:

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank You for your response. In your response preview tab mail value is null. I want that mail value to send email to user after confirmation.

Comment: @PankajDhote So，I recommend you use Azure AD Graph API:)

Comment: GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?api-version=1.6                                                     In this line myorganisation means azure active directory B2C domain right? One more thing, I am not a owner of this B2C. So is it necessary to have owner of B2C to fetch users detaiils?

Comment: Hi, @PankajDhote . You're right,`myorganisation` is the directory which the login account  belonged to . E.g. If you logined Azure AD Graph Explorer with` xxx@example.onmicrosoft.com`, the `myorganisation` is `example.onmicrosoft.com`. Also, the account should be a **global admin and a member of that directory**, NOT a guest user. You needn't be the owner of that directory.

Comment: Ohhh my god. I am very thank full to you. I am able to fetch users list with respective email from AADB2C now. Problem is solved now. thank you so much.

Comment: @PankajDhote  I’m glad for that my answer is helpful . :-)

Comment: Hi @Wayne Yang, Please help me to sort out one problem which I have posted today. I am trying to update AADB2C member password using Microsoft graph or Azure ad graph api. However I am not able to update password. It is showing me insufficient privileged error. I have tried with every permission. Could you please help me?